# How to link dll files for installer? c++

Tags: c++, installation, dll

I wanna know how to find and link all dll and lib files needed for running my application.  Because when I install application on other computer it gives error.

> (can't find gcc_dll files something like that).

Comment: Look at tools like [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com). You don't deploy `.lib` files, though. Those are only used for compiling, not running.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok,thank you for quick response! I really appreciate that.